# Twitter and SMS

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s-3, twitter

I have just installed the Twitter app on my Galaxy S3. I have discovered that there this an option in Twitter to receive tweets via SMS. Unfortunately, the country I am living in is not supported by Twitter. As far as I could see, everything that is possible in my situation is to write a tweet by sending an SMS to a UK number. However, [receiving tweets is not supported via this number](https://support.twitter.com/groups/34-apps-sms-and-mobile/topics/153-twitter-via-sms/articles/87284-how-to-tweet-with-your-phone-if-your-carrier-is-not-listed).

Is there a trick to overcome this limitation, so that I could *receive* tweets vis SMS?

Comment: That is *dependent* on your provider to be able to receive tweets via sms, by subscribing to a service where you would be charged for receiving tweets. Unless someone can confirm and correct me. We used to have it here on O2 (Ireland), by registering with a SMS subscriber code along with twitter a/c, then it got axed under some circumstances, and yes we got charged for receiving them! Why not use WiFi and receive it over that instead? Why do you want to receive it via SMS?

Comment: I travel a lot and wifi is not available everywhere all the time. Receiving updates via SMS will also work in a country where I don't have a data plan. Moreover, when not being abroad, this will allow me to have a better battery autonomy.